# What is the difference between 処置 and 措置?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

I wonder what is the difference between 処置【しょち】 and 措置【そち】. Could you please explain their differences on the next two phrases? :

> 是正処置【ぜせいしょち】 and  是正措置【ぜせいそち】

Answer (score 2):

The two terms are translated as corrective action and corrective measures.